# cannot get columnspan to make button fill the row of a Tkinter frame

Tags: python, button, tkinter, grid, columnspan

I have seen this [Python Tkinter - Set Entry grid width 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945467/python-tkinter-set-entry-grid-width-100/24945918) and this [columnspan in grid options dose't function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38169515/columnspan-in-grid-options-doset-function) (which was more useful) but cannot figure out how to get my 'Replot' button to fill the width of the row it is on. No matter what I set the columnspan of the widget to it never changes the width of the button. The button is in a frame with the other widgets and there is nothing else on that row.

[image]

***Code used for the buttons:***

```
button_quit2 = tk.Button(root, text = "Replot", command = rangesReplot, relief = tk.GROOVE, padx =30, pady =20 )
button_quit2.grid(row = 10, column = 0, columnspan=2)
```

Comment: Try `button_quit2.grid(row = 10, column = 0, columnspan=2,stikcy='nsew')` ?

Comment: @CoolCloud could you post that as an answer and I'll accept. Is columnspan on its own not enough? Your suggestion works.

Comment: its making me wait before accepting, 2more mins I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it to fill the row fully, use `sticky='nsew'`, like:

```
button_quit2 = tk.Button(frame2, text = "Replot", command = rangesReplot, relief = tk.GROOVE, padx =30, pady =20 )
button_quit2.grid(row = 10, column = 0, columnspan=2,sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W) #same as sticky='nsew'
```

`columnspan` allocates the button to have up to 2 columns but it does not completely "fill" or stretch the 2 columns.

Comment: Your terminology isn't quite correct. `columnspan` doesn't stretch the button. It simply allocates more than one column of space for the button.